# Desktop freeze when using the desktop as destination path for a sqlite database (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: php, freeze, sqlite

i wrote a little php testscript. The script insert 10000 numbers into a sqlite database. (I know, it is stupid and senseless to do 10000 insert statements in a loop.) But, when i using the home-directory as destination path for the sqlite database, everything is working fine. When i am using the desktop-directory as destination path, the desktop freeze and the desktop icons disappear. I tested the script on several 20.04 machines. The behavior is still the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// - HOME-DIRECTORY = OK
//$dbc = new PDO("sqlite:/home/<USERNAME>/numbers.sqlite");

// - DESKTOP-DIRECTORY = NOT OK [Schreibtisch = Desktop in Germany]
$dbc = new PDO("sqlite:/home/<USERNAME>/Schreibtisch/numbers.sqlite");

$dbc->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NUMBERS;");
$dbc->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NUMBERS (ID INTEGER);");

for ($x = 0; $x <= 1000; $x++) {
      $dbc->query("INSERT INTO NUMBERS ('ID') VALUES ('$x');");
}
?>
```

Comment: Easy workaround: do not place the sqlite database on the desktop. That does not make too much sense anyway. The problem is limitations in the way currently desktop icons are implemented.

Comment: Yes, as vanadium says, no way (and no logic) to work on the desktop folder. Create a test folder to work with. Working that way on the desktop folder is like car-surfing.